# Electrum Wallet How to use "Child Pays for Parent"

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, child-pays-for-parent

my transaction is here: https://blockchain.info/tr/tx/cb371b331e99eccb2d7447f4fe02417812ad066de21843fa156d4890e2cdf329
The reciever is a exchange wallet I don't know the reciever's private key.
it got stuck for hours and I need them immediately. I used electrum wallet for the first time and I have forgetten tick "replaceable". So now I can't change fee.
Once, I used "child pays for parent" property but now I couldn't see on electrum wallet. How can I unstuck it? or How can I use " Child Pays for Parent" feature ? I really searched for hours but I couldn't use it.

note: and I open for other answers.. for example how to stop braoadcasting transaction? is it possible?
This is the weakest side of bitcoin, I think :(

Comment: I am glad to see that your transaction confirmed eventually. Yes, it is a frustration for some that there is sometimes a delay. It is still a lot faster than driving to the exchange with cash but with Bitcoin there are no credit checks like there is required with credit card. The occasional delay is a small price to pay for the freedom of transacting without borders. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CPFP to confirm *that* transaction. It's impossible for one to rescue a low fee transaction using CPFP, **unless** he/she has a private key of at least one ddress of that transaction's outputs (in your case, it's impossible, because you don't).

That transaction's receiver can do CPFP, if he/she wants.

Hint: Use RBF (https://freedomnode.com/blog/75/how-to-fix-slow-bitcoin-transactions-with-replace-by-fee) or pay $4 on confirmtx.com

Comment: I understood but  I have forgetten tick "replaceable"..  :/

Comment: @MichealJ. Yes, you're right. Then why not pay $4?